# NW.JS failed to load grpc binary module

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, node-webkit, grpc, nwjs

I am trying to build an app which requires gRPC module. My app works perfectly fine while running from command prompt - **node server.js**

But, running the nwjs crashes and throws the error below -

What, I have tried -

**1.** If I enable **window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000';**
    then nwjs windows shows ***localhost*** This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect. and console gets cleared after showing the error so I commented this line to see the error. (error log is shown below)

```
Uncaught Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
Expected directory: node-webkit-v0.30.5-win32-x64-unknown
Found: [node-v57-win32-x64-unknown]
This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system
Original error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\BLACK\Desktop\NWJS Xperiments\NuOS-OAuth\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-webkit-v0.30.5-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node'
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\BLACK\Desktop\NWJS Xperiments\NuOS-OAuth\node_modules\grpc\src\grpc_extension.js:53:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:719:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:613:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:544:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\BLACK\Desktop\NWJS Xperiments\NuOS-OAuth\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:145:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
```

**2.** I have created **expected directory** manually - "Expected directory: node-webkit-v0.30.5-win32-x64-unknown" inside grpc module but now I see another error in dev tool, thought it has resolved the above problem.

```
Uncaught Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\\?\C:\Users\BLACK\Desktop\NWJS Xperiments\NuOS-OAuth\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-webkit-v0.30.5-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:749:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:613:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:544:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\BLACK\Desktop\NWJS Xperiments\NuOS-OAuth\node_modules\grpc\src\grpc_extension.js:32:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:719:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:613:32)
```

**3.** I have followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/5103) but no luck either. It throws another set of error.

After trying instructions in third point, I get this error

```
> grpc@1.11.3 install C:\Users\BLACK\Desktop\NWJS Xperiments\NuOS-OAuth\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'nw-gyp.cmd configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\BLACK\Desktop\NWJS Xperiments\NuOS-OAuth\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-webkit-v1.11.3-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\BLACK\Desktop\NWJS Xperiments\NuOS-OAuth\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-webkit-v1.11.3-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=1 --node_abi_napi=napi' (Error: spawn nw-gyp.cmd ENOENT)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\BLACK\Desktop\NWJS Xperiments\NuOS-OAuth\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:77:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:211:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:196:12)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\BLACK\\Desktop\\NWJS Xperiments\\NuOS-OAuth\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\BLACK\Desktop\NWJS Xperiments\NuOS-OAuth\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'nw-gyp.cmd configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\BLACK\Desktop\NWJS Xperiments\NuOS-OAuth\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-webkit-v1.11.3-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\BLACK\Desktop\NWJS Xperiments\NuOS-OAuth\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-webkit-v1.11.3-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=1 --node_abi_napi=napi' (Error: spawn nw-gyp.cmd ENOENT)
npm WARN nuos-healthcare@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN nuos-healthcare@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.11.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.11.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\BLACK\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-23T01_42_49_740Z-debug.log
```

Server.JS

```
const express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    socket = require('socket.io'),
    BigTable = require('@google-cloud/bigtable'),
    PubSub = require('@google-cloud/pubsub'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    cookieSession = require('cookie-session'),
    dotenv = require('dotenv').config(),
    config = require('./config/config'),
    gutils = require('./app/gutils'),
    authRoutes = require('./routes/auth-route'),
    passportSetup = require('./app/passport-setup'),
    app = express(),
    server = app.listen(3000),
    io = socket(server);

/*


App code removed 


*/


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login');
});

app.use(express.static('public'));

console.log('Server running on the port 3000 ...');
```

**P.S.** It works prefectly fine if I run **node server.js** command in cmd and then run the nwjs.

I am developing on windows 10 x64

Comment: What error do you get after you follow the linked instructions to rebuild gRPC for Node Webkit?

Comment: @murgatroid99 I have edited the question and added the log., please check

Comment: @murgatroid99 any suggestion? man!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with Node Webkit and I can't really tell what's going wrong from that build error.

Comment: Just ran into something similar to this after installing a node-version manger.  Lots of variables are different so not sure how much help it will be, but I resolved the issue by making sure the version of node I was running locally was the same version of node I was running in my CI builds.  Maybe thats a place to start looking?

Comment: are you sure you have the most recent npm version npm install npm@latest -g also sometimes visual studio etc needs to be installed as it installs required compilers for npm

Comment: @Silve2611 Yes I do have. As I have mentioned that it works fine but not with nwjs. I have got above errors while running it with nwjs otherwise app works fine. I was using nwjs to make the app distribute-able . Can you  suggest anything... I am so desperate.

Comment: What do you mean by it works fine but not nwjs? As long as you have not installed it in nwjs it cannot work. Can you add the error log from C:\Users\BLACK\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-23T01_42_49_740Z-debug.log ?

Answer (score 0):

My Approach would be a bit different. First of all you cannot have your node.js application and nwjs in the same folder structure because they install node-modules differently.

What you should do.

1. Create a basic NWJS Application as described in http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Getting%20Started/

You may choose the most recent version but remeber which version you have, because you need to know that for grpc instaltion.

2. Now you have to install grpc which you want to use.

   ```
   npm install grpc --build-from-source --runtime=node-webkit --target=0.32.2 --target_arch=x64
   ```

Be clear what NWJS version you have as described in 1. The most recent one is 0.32.2 
And set the target_arch to x64

3. Now copy the code step by step to your nwjs application and run it. NWJS is not the same as the node.js application. Therefore it is important that you separate the node.js code and the NWJS code.